# Sudden Gain of 100 Reputation Points

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus

Not long ago I suddenly received 100 points in every Stack Exchange site I was a member of. I got 100 points just for signing up in Meta Stack Exchange.

Is this a glitch, or a planned change?

Comment: Not a bug, and not a new change either. You reached 200 points on your [Life hacks account](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/4468/terry) so all of our accounts were awarded a 100 point bonus. From now on out all future accounts you create will be given that same bonus.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where i can find the answer, and sorry for not doing a good enough job of searching.

Answer (score 8):

You get 100 reputation points every time you sign up for a new Stack Exchange site once you become a trusted member (have at least 200 rep on at least one other site). You should see this message:

[image]

Comment: Not because they signed up anywhere new, no.

Comment: I didn't get this message, instead it was abou8 icons of the groups i am in with 100+ at the side.

Comment: You are missing some important points about the association bonus. The major one being the requirement of gaining 200 rep on a site.

Comment: I said "because you're a trusted member". I'm very well aware that trusted members gained at least 200 rep on any site.